# Unwanted lines in Geoserver layer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, shapefile

I recently upgraded my Geoserver from 2.1.1 to 2.17.1

Since I have done that, one of my layer show unwanted lines in his polygones :
[image]

This is what is show by a GetMap WMS request on the layer

The layer is from a PostGIS table filled with a shapefile read by FME.
In the previous Geoserver, the layer is OK.
In QGIS, shapefile is OK and data from table is OK too.
I tried to republish the layer and recreate the table without success

Comment: try unchecking the simplify polygons box on the postgis store page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This option is not checked in the postgis store page

Comment: does the shapefile display ok in GeoServer?

Comment: Are the geometries valid? (`st_isvalid()`). If you serve the data in a different CRS than the original one, are the projected geometries valid? (`st_isvalid(st_transform(..))`)

Comment: @IanTurton no, the image is from Geoserver layer previous (Openlayers)

Comment: @JGH,  I checked geometries with the function, they are all OK. I only do a reproject with FME when I fill the table.
Maybe something in the WMS configuration page ?

Comment: I meant does it work if the layer is from the shapefile directly instead of from PostGIS? does the log file show any errors?

Comment: I found nothing in Geoserver logs. But, as you suggested, I tried to import the layer in Geoserver and reproject it and it's all good. Thanks, I think I will use this solution